# Read columns from .txt file

Tags: java

I have a text file (archive.txt) which has 9 columns of data separated by a tab. I want to read the columns and perform simple math.

In the example below, I want to find the average cost(iCost) by adding all policies with high (3) or unlimited (4) in column cData then dividing by the total of high and unlimited. High and unlimited are represented by a 3 and 4, respectively, in the archive file.

There are two `System.out.println()` numbered 1 and 2. They are used to see where the program gets to. It doesn't make it past the first System.out.println.

```
public int highUnlimited() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = new Scanner("archive.txt");
    int iLargeBundle = 0;
    int iCost = 0;

    System.out.println("1");
    String cDate = input.next();
    int cMinutes = input.nextInt();
    int cData = input.nextInt();
    int cLength = input.nextInt();
    boolean cIntCalls = input.nextBoolean();
    String cReference = input.next();
    int cCostPerMonth = input.nextInt();
    String cFirstName = input.next();
    String cSecondName = input.next();

    System.out.println("2");
    if (cData == 3 || cData == 4) {
        iLargeBundle = iLargeBundle++;
        iCost = iCost + cCostPerMonth;
    }

    int iTotal = iLargeBundle / iCost;
    return iTotal;
}
```

These are the first two lines of the Archive file. They don't have headings normally

15-Sep-2016 2   1   12  N   MT230N  617 C Clark

25-Oct-2016 1   1   12  N   ED641N  475 Z Clark

Comment: You probably have an error? What does it say and doesn't it help you?

Comment: I assume you have a `main` method that somewhere calls the `highUnlimited()` method?

Comment: Please show us the first 2-3 lines from `archive.txt`.

Comment: Err, there is no loop in the code. So it only reads one row.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = new Scanner("archive.txt");
```

This opens up a scanner on the string `"archive.txt"`, not a file with that name.

If you wish to scan a file, you will need to do the following:

```
input = new Scanner(new File("archive.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have your code rewritten with comments showing you how to do it, i've added a loop in case you want to read all the lines of the file you are able to do it (in that loop i added the methods hasNextLine(), returns true if there is a line next and nextLine(), it jumps to the next line). It is important that you import java.io.*; to import the class file and  import java.util.*; to import that class Scanner. I hope i could help you.

```
public int highUnlimited(){
try{ //you all ways need to try catch the Exceptions when you use Scanner and File.

          File f = new File("path");      //We need to create first the file object this is 
                                          //done with the constructor File(String path)

          Scanner input = new Scanner(f); //You dont need the Scanner.in, the Scanner.in 
                                          //scanns input data from the terminal and we want
                                          //to scann it from a File. Th constructor 
                                          //Scanner(String path) that you used doesn't exist 
                                          //on java.
          int iLargeBundle = 0;
          int iCost = 0;
          String cDate, cReference, cFirstName, cSecondName; // I declare the variables outside so there
          int cMinutes, cData, cLength, cCostPerMonth;       //is no problem with the while
          boolean cIntCalls;
          int iTotal = 0; //I've used 0 as default value for iTotal 

          System.out.println("q");
      while(input.hasNextLine()){ //I use hasNextLine in case you have various lines of data in your file

                  cDate = input.next();
                  cMinutes = input.nextInt();
                  cData = input.nextInt();
                  cLength = input.nextInt();
                  cIntCalls = input.nextBoolean();
                  cReference = input.next();
                  cCostPerMonth = input.nextInt();
                  cFirstName = input.next();
                  cSecondName = input.next();
                  input.nextLine(); //To jump a line so it doesn't block on the while

              if (cData == 3 || cData ==4){
                  iLargeBundle++; //if you only want to add 1 to the variable with this is enough
                  iCost = iCost + cCostPerMonth;
              }
            }

              iTotal = iLargeBundle/iCost; //as iCost is = if it hasn't been modified here is going
                                               //to show an error because you can't divide by 0 so you have
                                               //to change this in cas iCost is 0
            }
            catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            } 
    return iTotal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you David! I've added a couple of lines from the archive file which are separated by a line. I've changed the ++iLargeBundle to iLargeBundle =  iLargeBundle + 1; but for some reason it only returns 1.

Comment: Oh sorry i misspelled it, it should be iLargeBundle++; , i hope that solves the problem.